# T-SQL Query / Count Rows by Partial Date Grouping

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table (in SQL Server 2008 R2, in case that matters), defined with the following rows. The `DateAdded` column is a `SmallDateTime` data type.

```
 ID    DateAdded
  1    2012-08-01 12:34:02
  2    2012-08-01 12:48:25
  3    2012-08-05 08:50:22
  4    2012-08-05 11:32:01
  5    2012-08-26 09:22:15 
  6    2012-08-26 13:42:02
  7    2012-08-27 08:22:12
```

What I need to do is count the rows that occur on the same YYYY/MM/DD value.  So the results I need to obtain would look like this...

```
DateAdded   QTY
2012-08-01  2  
2012-08-05  2  
2012-08-26  2  
2012-08-27  1
```

I can't figure out the syntax/expression to get this to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Comment: Please use the `{}` button when highlighting code samples or tabular output.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of the messy `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited the post, hopefully it's ok now?

Comment: Why did you add commas to the second output?

Comment: idk - just trying to post my question/problem quickly. Sorry if I didn't format it exactly perfect.  But thank you for the answers everyone!  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  DateAdded = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateAdded), 0), 
  QTY = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DateAdded), 0);
```

Or as Marc rightly pointed out (I spent more time looking at the formatting botches than the tags):

```
SELECT 
  DateAdded = CONVERT(DATE, DateAdded), 
  QTY = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, DateAdded);
```

Comment: Or just `GROUP BY CAST(DateAdded AS DATE)` since it's 2008 R2